# Catch result code from sqoop import in shell

Tags: sqoop

How can I catch successful execution of sqoop import in shell?
I would like to execute a subsequent import like this:

```
result=$(sqoop import ...)

if [ $result > 0 ] ; then
    sqoop import ...
else
    exit 1
fi
```

(I am aware that this could be done with oozie, however, for various reasons I need to do this via shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this kind of pattern in a shell script (For example, `run_sqoop.sh`).

```
#!/bin/bash

sqoop import <rest-of-command-parameters>
result=$?
echo $result

if [ "$result" -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Fail"
    echo "Fixing and running again"
    sqoop import <updated-rest-of-command-parameters>
fi
```

Make the file an executable

```
$ chmod 755 run_sqoop.sh
```

If the first import succeeds, the output will be:

```
output-logs-from-sqoop-command-execution
:
0
OK
```

If the first import fails, the output will be:

```
output-logs-from-first-sqoop-command-execution
:
1
Fail
Fixing and running again
output-logs-from-second-sqoop-command-execution
:
```